# Trying to start javascript koans - can't even load the first codeset

Tags: javascript

Here is my error:

```
jasmine.ExpectationResult@file:///E:/Dropbox/---%20Javascript%20---/javascript-koans-master/lib/jasmine/jasmine.js:94 @file:///E:/Dropbox/---%20Javascript%20---/javascript-koans-master/koans/AboutExpects.js:5
```

So is the problem that I have spaces in my filepath?

Or is it those colons I see after each .js file?

The js files definitely don't have those colons when I look in the directories in github.

https://github.com/mrdavidlaing/javascript-koans/tree/master/lib/jasmine

Comment: JavaScript koans follow [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) -- roughly, the tests/assertions intentionally fail at first and you have to figure out how to edit each so they pass. The URL shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The :94 and :5 indicate line numbers, i.e., that your test failures (that @JonathanLonowski is hinting at) can be tracked down by possibly looking at AboutExpects.js, line 5.

Comment: I thought I was supposed to see some buggy code in my browser and fix it. So I'm supposed to edit the js file in an external editor before it will even load? I'll go look at those lines and see what's up. Thx

Comment: @user1544566 Yeah. "*The first error will be in koans/AboutExpects.js. Fix the first test and refresh the browser. Rinse and repeat until all tests turn green.*" ([source](https://github.com/mrdavidlaing/javascript-koans#running-the-koans-from-a-browser))